# Existence of element of order $l$ dividing the order of the group

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

In this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/349992/order-of-kernel-of-a-homomorphism , someone say that since $l$ divides $m$, we can say that there exists some element $x \in \ker (\varphi)$ such that $o(x)=l$.

But why is it true? I mean isn't it is true only for $l$ is a prime? (by Cauchy's theorem), may anyonne please explains it to me, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

In general, it is not true that if an integer $t$ divides the order of a subgroup $H,$ then $H$ contains an element of order $t,$ though of course it is true when $t$ is prime, as you mentioned. To give an explicit example where $H$ is the kernel of a homomorphism, take $G = S_{4}.$ Then $G$ has a normal subgroup $H$ (which is a Klein $4$-group), and there is a homomorphism $\phi: G \to S_{3}$  with ${\rm ker} \phi = H.$ Then $H$ has order divisible by $4,$ but contains no element of order $4$.

Answer (score 2):

In that post the group was cyclic, and for those groups is true:
$\frac{n}{l}$ has order $l$ in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thank quimey, but I still have a problem: we don't know whether there is a element of order $m$ or not, so why $l | m$ will imply the desired result...?

Comment: Sherly, you are sherly! I recognized you. No need to have two accounts. Especcially with the name nicknames. More importantly, this is not an answer, it is a comment. I guess you don't have enough reputation to comment?

Comment: @Sherly: You accidentally created a duplicate account; with fewer than 50 reputation points, [an account can only comment on its own questions and answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work/19757#19757). Follow [the instructions here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge) to merge your accounts.